# Coding in PySpark dataframe so slow

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm a beginner in PySpark. I start with some data from Oracle databases, which has about 20000 rows. I found PySpark data frame is very inconvenient to use compared to pandas.
For example, if I want to perform some very basic methods, such as .head(), .show() or save to csv, in the interactive mode. It takes very long time to finish.
For those who are experienced in using PySpark, how do you manipulate/clean your pyspark data frame? It's hard to imagine one can finish the code without looking at any intermediate steps/results.

Also, I don't want to convert the PySpark dataframe to pandas. I'd like to learn how to use PySpark.
Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a specific piece of code that you'd like to optimize? Meanwhile, check out this link about Lazy Evaluation in Apache Spark (https://data-flair.training/blogs/apache-spark-lazy-evaluation/) Maybe it answers some of your questions

Comment: Next time, please post a specific code. Now this question is too broad, I must vote for closing.